# Unicode characters in LaTeX

Tags: unicode

How do we display unicode characters in LaTex using the corresponding string?

I copied the following from an application:

[image: Original]

I got this as the LaTex string:

```
\begin{equation}
\alpha  \beta  \unicode{043e} \copyright  \text{\` a} \unicode{01b0}
\end{equation}
```

But my TeXMaker can't interpret it:

[image: In TeXMaker]

I found some related posts however couldn't draw a conclusion on how to proceed. A clean set of instructions would be very helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % for Japanese - just for testing
\setCJKmainfont{Arial Unicode MS} % for Japanese
\usepackage[russian,english,japanese]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\char"0416 \char"6771 \char"043E \char"01B0
\begin{equation}
\alpha  \beta  \text{\char"043E} \copyright  \text{\` a} \text{\char"01B0}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Mention capital "E" and "B" in hex codes, it's important. `unicode-math` package is also required.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Must compile in xelatex or lualatex, and choose a font that provides all your symbols.  Use `\symbol{}` to access unicode slots.

Also key is that the hexidecimal digits beyond 9 must specified with capital letters (`"043E` rather than `"043e`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\alpha  \beta  \text{\symbol{"043E}} \copyright  \text{\` a} 
  \text{\symbol{"01B0}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]